# Paint operation is not being executed but the system out does

Tags: java, if-statement, paint

I'm working on a application that draws boxes and connects them with lines. Each line has corners (dots). The user can add dots by right clicking the line. Then the dot gets a location set.

The paint method of the diagram loops through all the dots and checks if they are custom (simple; return (location != -1)), when they are it must paint a circle image on that location.

Now i really tearing out my hear because it executes in debug mode but don't draw! I placed a system out to check and that is executed as normal. But the if statement works if I place a ! sign in front of the if statement. I really can't find the problem.

The paint method:

```
public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.setColor(Color.RED);//_lineColor);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(DEFAULT_LINE_SIZE));

    for(Line2D line : _lines) {
        g.draw(line);
    }

    if(_isHover) {
        for(ConnectionDot dot : _connectionDots) {
            if(dot.isUserDot()) {
                System.out.println("YEAH!!!");
                //TODO: dot hover?
                g.drawImage(_icoConnectionNor.getImage(), dot.getX()-8, dot.getY()-8, null);

                //g.drawString("What?", dot.getX(), dot.getY());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Hell No!");

                g.drawString("What?", dot.getX(), dot.getY());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Dot class:

```
public class ConnectionDot {
//...
private int _userDotQueueLoc;

/**
 * Create new dot.
 *
 * @param gridController reference to the grid controller.
 * @param grid Grid position of the dot.
 */
public ConnectionDot(GridController gridController, Grid grid){
    _gridController = gridController;
    _gridPos = grid;
    _userDotQueueLoc = -1;
}

/**
 * Create new user dot.
 *
 * @param gridController reference to the grid controller.
 * @param grid Grid position of the dot.
 * @param userDotLocation Location of user dot.
 */
public ConnectionDot(GridController gridController, Grid grid, int userDotLocation){
    this(gridController, grid);
    _userDotQueueLoc = userDotLocation;
}

/**
 * Returns true if the dot is custom.
 *
 * @return Flag.
 */
public boolean isUserDot(){
    return (_userDotQueueLoc != -1);
}
```

}

Console output:
Hell No!
Hell No!
Hell No!
Hell No!
YEAH!!!
Hell No!
Hell No!
Hell No!
Hell No!
YEAH!!!
... you get the point

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: It must not be drawling where you think it is.  Like Andrew said, you need to post a SSCCE.

Comment: Ok.. just looked at the link and really don't know what to do with that. (mucho reading :P) But i found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your x/y values of the dot are incorrect.

Painting a String at (0, 0) will not show the string since drawString expects the point to be the bottom/left, not top/left.

One the other hand drawing an image uses the top/left, so maybe by subtracting 8 you are moving the image off the panel.

But as other have pointed out the only way to know for sure is to post a SSCCE.

Comment: Thanks! it was not really the thing but it made me think about the location of the dot. The dot's location is a grid and i made a mistake in the addUserDot method that added the x and y points instead of the grids location.. So it was drawing in location 3020,2393 or so.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u need to forcefully repaint the screen? It might be that it does read your actions, however, it doesn't display it. I've never worked with 'Graphics2D', so I don't know the method for that, but u should be able to find it easilly.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The println is seen on the console so the paint method is being called. The problem is elsewhere.